# How does reserved_at work in Laravel queue?

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

As far I know in Laravel Queue `reserved_at` is set if a worker has reserved the job so it doesn't overlap with other workers. On default it is `null`.

When queue crash because of errors in code - job is going to failed - and that is clear.
But when server has crash and there is some kind of timeout - job put timestamp in `reserved_at` - and nothing else happens. Job is not failed. I do not get it. I have just ONE worker.

That job is not continued, just stack in database - I do not know what to do with this.
I just want to ask how do you deal with this `reserved_at`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the `reserved_at` is a field where you can set when you wanna run the job.
if you wanna fill it you just have to add `delay(the date when you want it to run`) in the line where you dispatched your job example :

```
$this->dispatch($variable)->delay(Carbon::today()->addMinutes(5));
```